# How can I implement push notifications for iOS and Android devices using SendBird

Tags: sendbird

I am implementing a chat feature in my iOS and Android app and want to setup the push notification.

How can I implement push notifications for iOS and Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

According to the help center:
There are two ways to implement push notifications for your app:

1. Built-in push notification services

SendBird supports iOS and Android push notifications through FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging, previously Google Cloud Messaging), and APNs (Apple Push Notification Service).

Please refer to the following guide:

Android: https://docs.sendbird.com/android#push_notifications
iOS: https://docs.sendbird.com/ios#push_notifications

2. Webhooks

If you want to implement your own custom push notifications, you should use Webhooks. Webhooks can be enabled from the SendBird Dashboard under Settings - Notifications - Webhooks.

The callback URL that you specify will be called whenever messages are sent in a channel.

Please refer to the following documentation:

https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#webhooks